# vue-router: nested routes on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, vue.js, vuejs2, responsive, vue-router

I am quite new to Vue and am making a project that can be used on both Desktop and Mobile.

I am using **vue-router** to manage the routing in my project and I have **nested views** for some pages.

*For example:*

- I have a settings page
- This page has a navigation role and 2 sub-routes (like *account* or *preferences*)
- So I have 3 components, one `Settings` (do the *nav* and have a `router-view`). And one for each nested route.

Here in my `router` configuration

```
{
    path: '/settings',
    name: 'settings',
    component: Settings,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'account',
            name: 'settings-account',
            component: Account
        },
        {
            path: 'preferences',
            name: 'settings-preferences',
            component: Preferences
        }
    ]
}
```

Here in `Settings.vue`

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <!-- some router-link s -->
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

My question is: When the user is on desktop, the `router-view` and the `nav` are on the **same screen**, which is fine.

But when the user is on a mobile, I would like to load another full page like `/settings/account` instead of having everything on the same.

Like a classic master-detail flow.

How can I implement this ? Should I declare another component and another route like

```
{
    path: '/settings/account',
    name: 'settings-account-mobile',
    component: SettingsAccount 
}
```

Or is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: What about rendering component conditionally inside one of your components then hide the navigation link on mobile.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was planning to do ! Seems the best answer today.